# Why does Azure Managed Identity show as Invalid Resource ID

Tags: azure, azure-web-app-service, azure-keyvault, azure-managed-identity

I am trying to use Azure Key Vault to store the connection string for my web app.

My first step was to create a managed identity for my app service.

[image]

Having done this and having an object ID available I navigate to my key vault and grant the previous identity permissions to Get & List secrets

When I navigate to key vault secrets I get the following:

[image]

To me this contradicts what I've just set. I have List permission on.
Furthermore checking on the created managed identity in CLI using:

```
az identity show --ids b38196d2-be05-4681-b93a-828d4cd63034
invalid resource ID: b38196d2-be05-4681-b93a-828d4cd63034
```

The web app service is in a resource group along with database/server. The key vault is in another resource group. For my CI/dev I have created a service principal using:

```
az ad sp create-for-rbac -n appx --role contributor --scopes "/subscriptions/d95201ae-f361-4c30-a527-581695bfab01/resourceGroups/example-resources" --sdk-auth
```

And stored the output in my github secrets as AZURE_CREDENTIALS. This has worked fine. As does my web app with the test connection string still in appsettings.json.

I don't understand what's wrong with my managed identity.

Comment: Can you provide a screenshot of the access policies you have configured?

Comment: "@Ked-Mardemootoo I have changed my access policy type from vault access, used in the above example, to role-based. After completing this configuration I still get the same "Invalid resource" message re:app-service | Identity Maybe I misunderstand. I thought this was my Service Identity required to access the Key Vault. I can still provide access policies although my question has changed. Now I am trying to confirm that my app is using key vault.

Comment: Hello , you might have just added access policy for your managed user identity in the keyvault / you might have not added list permission for keyvault secrets for your user principal name ?

Comment: can you please check the access policy for you in the keyvault ?

Comment: @AnsumanBal-MT I may not understand. But my question refers to a web app using a Key Vault connection string secret. This is not a user principal but a service principal. I have now changed my vault to role-based. I was using vault access (which as I understand uses managed identity) I have progressed the task but have different problems now :/

Comment: Dave, as per your screenshot when you are looking for secrets from portal , it uses user's access policy , i mean who has logged in to the azure portal

Comment: its better if you can please show us the keyvault access policy that you have configured for that keyvault

Answer (score 1):

As AnsumanBal-MT mentioned, (going back to what you've mentioned in the question), as far as we can tell you only added the WebApp's identity to the KV's secret access policies. You did not add your own User Principal to the KV's secret policies - which is why you were seeing that error that says you're unauthorized to view the content. The AppService was allowed but you were not.

This error you're seeing below is because you're not using the command properly. It does **not** take an identity's object ID as parameter.

```
az identity show --ids b38196d2-be05-4681-b93a-828d4cd63034
invalid resource ID: b38196d2-be05-4681-b93a-828d4cd63034
```

Looking at the [`az identity` documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cli/azure/identity?view=azure-cli-latest#az_identity_show-optional-parameters), you need to parse the complete resource ID of the AppService that you can find under the properties section of your WebApp.

E.g.:

```
az identity show --ids /subscriptions/mysubscription/resourceGroups/myrg/providers/Microsoft.Web/sites/myapp
```

Comment: Thanks for feedback/suggestions. Before I go any further I should say that I have only now found out that Key Vault needs Azure AD. I have not been using Azure AD Connect.