# Set Azure DevOps Pipeline Permissions via API

Tags: azure, powershell, permissions, devops

I am trying to set Azure DevOps Pipeline permission using the following API from Powershell:

PATCH
[https://dev.azure.com/{organization}/{project}/_apis/pipelines/pipelinepermissions?api-version=7.0-preview.1](https://dev.azure.com/%7Borganization%7D/%7Bproject%7D/_apis/pipelines/pipelinepermissions?api-version=7.0-preview.1)

I have successfully achieved this for most resource types (Environments, Service Connections, and Variable Groups, however when I try to use it to set permission for repositories, I get the following error:

> Invoke-RestMethod : {"$id":"1","innerException":null,"message":"Invalid resource id. a0946c7f-e505-48be-ba1b-1044d4128a4e","typeName":"System.ArgumentException, mscorlib","typeKey":"ArgumentException","errorCode":0,"eventId":0}

My JSON body is as follows:

> [ { "resource": { "type": "repository", "id": "a0946c7f-e505-48be-ba1b-1044d4128a4e", "name": "Source" }, "pipelines": [ { "id": 2436, "authorized": true } ] } ]

Any help would be much appreciated.

###Additional details:

Using the following API (replacing `{organization}` and `{project}` with my org and project):

```
GET https://dev.azure.com/{organization}/{project}/_apis/git/repositories?api-version=7.0
```

I get (replacing `{organization}` and `{project}` with my org and project):

```
{
    "value": [
        {
            "id": "a0946c7f-e505-48be-ba1b-1044d4128a4e",
            "name": "Source",
            "url": "https://dev.azure.com/{organization}/70a034e6-3c03-47c3-bec1-4f6094e46519/_apis/git/repositories/a0946c7f-e505-48be-ba1b-1044d4128a4e",
            "project": {
                "id": "70a034e6-3c03-47c3-bec1-4f6094e46519",
                "name": "{project}",
                "description": "This Azure DevOps project is for the {project} development team",
                "url": "https://dev.azure.com/{organization}/_apis/projects/70a034e6-3c03-47c3-bec1-4f6094e46519",
                "state": "wellFormed",
                "revision": 3597,
                "visibility": "private",
                "lastUpdateTime": "2023-09-01T13:00:04.513Z"
            },
            "defaultBranch": "refs/heads/main",
            "size": 741,
            "remoteUrl": "https://{organization}@dev.azure.com/{organization}/{project}/_git/Source",
            "sshUrl": "git@ssh.dev.azure.com:v3/{organization}/{project}/Source",
            "webUrl": "https://dev.azure.com/{organization}/{project}/_git/Source",
            "isDisabled": false,
            "isInMaintenance": false
        },
        {
            "id": "ad4906a1-db58-4c6d-ae17-1d49d56b5abe",
            "name": "Pipelines",
            "url": "https://dev.azure.com/{organization}/70a034e6-3c03-47c3-bec1-4f6094e46519/_apis/git/repositories/ad4906a1-db58-4c6d-ae17-1d49d56b5abe",
            "project": {
                "id": "70a034e6-3c03-47c3-bec1-4f6094e46519",
                "name": "{project}",
                "description": "This Azure DevOps project is for the {project} development team",
                "url": "https://dev.azure.com/{organization}/_apis/projects/70a034e6-3c03-47c3-bec1-4f6094e46519",
                "state": "wellFormed",
                "revision": 3597,
                "visibility": "private",
                "lastUpdateTime": "2023-09-01T13:00:04.513Z"
            },
            "defaultBranch": "refs/heads/main",
            "size": 1291,
            "remoteUrl": "https://{organization}@dev.azure.com/{organization}/{project}/_git/Pipelines",
            "sshUrl": "git@ssh.dev.azure.com:v3/{organization}/{project}/Pipelines",
            "webUrl": "https://dev.azure.com/{organization}/{project}/_git/Pipelines",
            "isDisabled": false,
            "isInMaintenance": false
        }
    ],
    "count": 2
}
```

Using the following API (replacing `{organization}` and `{project}` with my org and project)::

```
GET https://dev.azure.com/{organization}/{project}/_apis/pipelines/pipelinepermissions/{resourceType}/{resourceId}?api-version=7.0-preview.1

GET https://dev.azure.com/{organization}/{project}/_apis/pipelines/pipelinepermissions/repository/a0946c7f-e505-48be-ba1b-1044d4128a4e?api-version=7.0-preview.1
```

I get the following:

```
{
    "$id": "1",
    "innerException": null,
    "message": "Invalid resource id. a0946c7f-e505-48be-ba1b-1044d4128a4e",
    "typeName": "System.ArgumentException, mscorlib",
    "typeKey": "ArgumentException",
    "errorCode": 0,
    "eventId": 0
}
```

Comment: You link is not valid.  If code is old it probably won't work.   Azure uses OAUTH2 where you first request a token/cookie.  The after you get the token you add the token to each request.

Comment: The links were taken from the microsoft website so they must be correct: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/azure/devops/approvalsandchecks/pipeline-permissions?view=azure-devops-rest-7.0

Comment: The links work, and I have no issue with the tokens; this is not an authentication issue or a URI issue unless I am missing something. I know that 7.1 is available but I am using 7.0

Comment: The link is a preview 7.0.  See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69653453/why-does-azure-managed-identity-show-as-invalid-resource-id

Comment: Thank you, but your link is irrelevant as this is not an authentication or an issue with Azure authentication. This issue is now resolved, see below.

Comment: I don't want to confuse people who read this posting.  The issue is an authentication issue.  You were only providing the id and solution was to add both the id and type.

Answer (score 0):

> Invoke-RestMethod {"$id":"1","innerException":null,"message":"Invalid resource id.a0946c7f-e505-48be-ba1b-1044d4128a4e","typeName":"System.ArgumentException,
> mscorlib","typeKey":"ArgumentException","errorCode":0,"eventId":0}

It looks like you are using an invalid resource id in your request body.

To get the correct resource id and resource type, refer this [SO-Thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74477827/azure-devops-api-pipelinepermissions-resourcetype-infos) to get all the resource list present in your pipeline and then you can get resource information and associated pipelines in that resource id by using below url.

*URL-*

```
GET https://dev.azure.com/{organization}/{project}/_apis/pipelines/pipelinepermissions/{resourceType}/{resourceId}?api-version=7.0-preview.1
```

Try to check if your resource id is exist by using the above URL.

*I am using the following Powershell  script to make the PATCH call-*

```
$connectionToken="PAT"
    
$token = [System.Convert]::ToBase64String([System.Text.Encoding]::ASCII.GetBytes(":$($connectionToken)"))
    
$url="https://dev.azure.com/{Org-name}/{project-name}/_apis/pipelines/pipelinepermissions?api-version=7.0-preview.1"
    
$body=@"
[
  {
    "resource": {
      "type": "endpoint",
      "id": "<resource id>",
      "name": "Default"
    },
    "pipelines": [
      {
        "id": <pipeline id>,
        "authorized": true
      }
    ]
  }
]
"@
    
$response = Invoke-RestMethod -Uri $url -Headers @{Authorization = "Basic $token"} -Method PATCH -Body $body -ContentType application/json

$response | ConvertTo-Json -Depth 4
```

**`Output:`**

[image]

Comment: Thanks; however I am only having issued with repositories, not endpoints. The repo Id is a GUID and does exist. If I use the call you are suggesting, I get exactly the same message for my repo Id which 100% exists and is correct.

Comment: Just to confirm my code works for Enviromens, EndPoints and Variables it only fails for repositories with invalid Id when I use the GUID which is retrieved and validated before I use it.

Comment: are you using the resource id of `repository` resource type? can you share the screenshot of your get call where you are fetching the resource id and type?

Comment: Please see ###Additional details above. This was done using a browser having authenticated to Azure DevOps

Comment: Refer https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74477827/azure-devops-api-pipelinepermissions-resourcetype-infos, you are fetching the resource id and resource type incorrectly

Comment: Here you are retrieving the git repositories. In order to update the pipeline permissions to need to check if that pipeline has that resource type in it, like I am checking [here](https://i.imgur.com/3prZvXq.png) and then I am doing [this](https://i.imgur.com/qYibJdv.png). After these two calls I am doing the Patch call

Comment: That's a Yes and Yes. Please see my additional details; the Repo Id is correct I've validated this. The issue appears to be the repo GUID is invalid despite it being correct. The "_apis/pipelines/pipelinepermissions/{resourceType}/{resourceId}" does not seem to accept the GUID for resource type repository.

Comment: you are using https://dev.azure.com/{organization}/{project}/_apis/git/repositories?api-version=7.0 to get the repositories instead you should use GET https://dev.azure.com/{organization}/{project}/_apis/build/definitions/{definitionId}/resources?api-version=7.0-preview.1

Comment: Sorry, I don't understand; I'm not trying to list resources I am trying to add them to the pipeline. To add them you need to use /_apis/pipelines/pipelinepermissions/{resourceType}/{resourceId} or am I missing something, your suggestion list the resources but how do I then add the missing permissions.

Comment: I can confirm I have tried your suggestion, and the repo is not listed even after manually granting access to the pipeline in the repository settings.  I have also checked other pipelines, and I can see that before I add permissions, they are not listed; after I add permissions, they are listed.

Comment: refer https://github.com/microsoft/terraform-provider-azuredevops/issues/7, here also they are suggesting to first get the resource types like [this](https://i.imgur.com/gmqKOHU.png), if type: "repository" is there in response body, then you can use that id in your patch call to grant permission

Answer (score 0):

When using:

[https://dev.azure.com/{organization}/{project}/_apis/pipelines/pipelinepermissions/{resourceType}/{resourceId}?api-version=7.0-preview.1](https://dev.azure.com/%7Borganization%7D/%7Bproject%7D/_apis/pipelines/pipelinepermissions/%7BresourceType%7D/%7BresourceId%7D?api-version=7.0-preview.1)

It turns out that for the {resourceType} repository, you need to concatenate the {project.Id} and the {repository.Id} as the {resourceId}, both of which are GUIDs:

For the:

[https://dev.azure.com/{organization}/{project}/_apis/pipelines/pipelinepermissions?api-version=7.0-preview.1](https://dev.azure.com/%7Borganization%7D/%7Bproject%7D/_apis/pipelines/pipelinepermissions?api-version=7.0-preview.1)

The Json should be as follows:

```
[ 
    { 
        "resource": { 
            "type": "repository", 
            "id": "{project.Id}.{repository.Id}", 
            "name": "{repository.Name}" 
        }, 
        "pipelines": [ 
            { 
                "id": {pipeline.Id}, 
                "authorized": true 
            } 
        ] 
    } 
]
```

Once again, thanks for your help :)

Comment: Even you can take the I'd from get call itself

Comment: My issue was a simple case of appending the project.Id to the repository.Id. Getting the repository.Id the way I did was fine I just needed to add the project.Id when passing it to the "_apis/pipelines/pipelinepermissions?api-version=7.0-preview.1" API in the format of "{project.Id}.{repository.Id}". Even after adding the permission, if I use your suggestion, the repository is not listed as a resource type. I suspect the latter is a bug as the repository permission is added, and the pipeline works as expected.